# How to use jsoncpp in portable native client

Tags: google-nativeclient, jsoncpp

I have included *json.h* in my project, but compiler says:

```
undefined reference to 'Json::Value' or 'Json::Reader'
```

May I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Like any other library, you need to install it if you're going to use it. Try this:

1. Clone [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/).
2. Following the instructions in that project's README.txt, set up your development environment.
3. `make_all.sh jsoncpp`

If all that succeeds, then you'll have the jsoncpp library installed on your development machine for NACL_SDK_ROOT, and something like `#include <json/reader.h>` will succeed.